# Regex for registration number

Tags: regex

I'm new with regular expretions. Don't know how to do.
Here it's a regex format

```
reg_no xx(F/S)-(BS/MS)(CS/SE)-x
```

example of registration number

```
reg_no 13F-BSSE-4
```

Solution is

```
"/^(reg)_(no) [0-9]{2}[(BS)|(MS)]{2}[(CS)|(SE)]{2}\-[0-9]{1}$/"
```

Comment: Try [`^reg_no [0-9]{2}[A-Z]-(?:BS|MS)(?:CS|SE)-[0-9]$`](https://regex101.com/r/nT9qJ2/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^reg_no [0-9]{2}[FS]-(?:[BM]S)(?:CS|SE)-[0-9]$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eX2pC8/1)**